# PHP - Create random hash string for email closed loop verification

Tags: php, linux, encryption, random

I am currently working on a project which requires closed loop email verification. As part of the process I need to generate a random hash string which can be appended to a link sent to the user. When they click the link they will be directed to my site at which time the app will confirm the hash and complete the registration process. For all my hashing I have been using:

```
hash('sha256', $string);
```

But for this process, I need to seed `$string` with a random value. I have Zend Framework available and was looking to do something like this:

```
$crypt = new Zend_Filter_Encrypt_Mcrypt(array());

$hash = hash('sha256', $crypt->getVector());
```

My question is, is this a viable algorithm for generating random hash codes?

Here is the `Zend_Filter_Encrypt_Mcrypt::setVector()` method (generates the value returned via `getVector()`:

```
public function setVector($vector = null)
{
    $cipher = $this->_openCipher();
    $size   = mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($cipher);
    if (empty($vector)) {
        $this->_srand();
        if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN' && version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0', '<')) {
            $method = MCRYPT_RAND;
        } else {
            if (file_exists('/dev/urandom') || (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN')) {
                $method = MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM;
            } elseif (file_exists('/dev/random')) {
                $method = MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM;
            } else {
                $method = MCRYPT_RAND;
            }
        }
        $vector = mcrypt_create_iv($size, $method);
    } else if (strlen($vector) != $size) {
        require_once 'Zend/Filter/Exception.php';
        throw new Zend_Filter_Exception('The given vector has a wrong size for the set algorithm');
    }

    $this->_encryption['vector'] = $vector;
    $this->_closeCipher($cipher);

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()

Comment: @Jack: Thanks for the suggestion, interesting read. How many bytes have you used? I am going to keep the question open to see if more responses trickle in. Kind of lazy and not really wanting to recompile php ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with ZF, but something that has the word `Encrypt` in it just sounds like the wrong approach.

<strike>The `->getVector()` sounds similar to what the Initialization Vector does in symmetric encryption; the problem is that such a vector doesn't need to be cryptographically safe, just random. For instance, it may well be just implemented as `uniqid(mt_rand())` or something.</strike>

`->getVector()` uses `mcrypt` to first initialize the encryption cipher to know how big the IV should be; this is typically 8 bytes, but it largely depends on the block size of the used cipher. The thing is, **you're not encrypting anything**; you just want a random sequence.

The better way to get a random sequence is by using `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` with a size of 8 bytes.

In its absence, you could also read from an entropy file such as `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom`. Afterwards you can run it through `binh2hex()` to generate a hexadecimal string.

Something like this is pretty rudimentary but should work on Linux'y systems:

```
$rnd = bin2hex(file_get_contents('/dev/urandom', false, null, 0, 8));
```

As a fallback for Windows, you can still use something like:

```
$rnd = hash('sha256', uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
```

Comment: I updated post with contents of how Zend generates the vector. It does attempt to use the entropy files you mention, which leads me to think that it would be a viable api in order to generate random strings.

Comment: @MikePurcell It's still overkill to use `mcrypt` for it though; does your installation not have `openssl`?

Comment: No, but I have full control over the servers so I can re-compile no problem. I am a minimalist, and only add needed modules.

Comment: @MikePurcell Well, if your code will run on a Linux'ish server, you should have `/dev/[u]random`.

Comment: Ya most definitely on linux, your first example looks interesting. I'll do some tire kicking and report back.

Comment: `uniqid(mt_rand(), true);` is slightly better for your fallback on Windows (:

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into ircmaxell's [CryptLib](https://github.com/ircmaxell/PHP-CryptLib) which has a fairly comprehensive suite of random generation features. If you use the medium strength random string generator, like so:

```
$generator = ( new CryptLib\Random\Factory() )->getMediumStrengthGenerator();
$string = $generator->generateString(LENGTH);
```

The library will use multiple cryptographically secure sources and run them through a mixer to generate a string. It's worth checking into if you just want a simple solution and don't want to recompile PHP with openssl.

See the [readme](https://github.com/ircmaxell/PHP-CryptLib/blob/master/README.markdown#secure-random-numberstring-generation) on secure string generation.

Comment: "The current version is considered Alpha. This means that it is ready enough to start testing and vetting the library, but not feature complete and not production ready." :(

Comment: @MikePurcell Ah, I didn't even realize it was still in alpha :/ In that case using `/dev/urandom` is probably a good call.

Comment: Np, thanks for the suggest tho. Always interested in solid project offerings from other devs.